# Android: Gallery w/ multiple images, zoom and switch

Tags: android, imageview, gallery

I'm tasked to alter an application of mine. Currently, the app displays 4 images (after downloading them) in a gallery. The gallery allows for easy image switching via swipe.

Now, I should implement an imagezoom, which in itself isn't too hard, I've found plenty of examples on Stackoverflow alone. But one thing strikes me as odd: How do I or the widgets I use separate a moving of the zoomed in image from a motion to switch to the next image?

I imagine that it must be possible to dispatch the events to the right handler: When the image is zoomed out full, the left swipe should switch to the next image, while zoomed in even a little would move the image to the left.

Can anybody point me in the direction of how to accomplish this? Where do I hop on to handle the touch events myself, and where do I propagate them in the two cases I described above?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: A possible way is... intercepting touch event and dispatch it for swiping to next image when image's border is visible. In deatail, if you want swipe right, you have to check if right border of image is visible. Until it happens, touch events stay on ImageView. When it happens, touch event has to be intercepted and dispatched to SwipeView. Sorry for my bad english. I hope concept is clear